# Build stateful chain for different events and assign global ID in spark

Tags: java, algorithm, scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

We are working with `spark 1.6` and we are trying to keep global identity for similar events. There can be few "groups"of events with identical ID (in the example as number. letters are added just for uniqueness). And we know that some of these events are similar so we are able to connect them.  We want to keep something like:

```
Z -> 1, 2, 3
X -> 4
```

so in a future if some events with id 4 will come we can assign `X` as a global identity.

Please check example for better illustration:

Let's say we have some streaming data coming into spark job.

```
1a
1b
2c
2d
2e
3f
3g
3h
4i
```

Since event 1 is our first appearance we want to assign `1 to Z`. 
Next what we know is that 1b and 2c are similar. so we want to keep somewhere `2->1` mapping. Same thing is for 2e and 3f so we need mapping `3-2`. So for now we have 3 pairs `1->Z`, `2->1`, `3->2`.

And we want to create "historical" path: `Z <- 1 <- 2 <- 3`
At the end we will have all events with `ID = Z`.

```
1a -> Z
1b -> Z
2c -> Z
2d -> Z
2e -> Z
3f -> Z
3g -> Z
3h -> Z
4i -> X
```

We tried to use `mapwithstate` but only thing we were able to do was that  `2->1` and `3->2`. With `mapwithstate` we were not able to get state for "parent" in state for current event - eg. current event 3 with parent 2 and not able to get `2 -> 1` and neither `1 -> Z`.

Is it possible to have some global mapping for this? We already tried accumulators and broadcast but looks like not very suitable. And we were not able to replace events 1 for first mapping and events 2 for second mapping with `Z`.

If new event `5` will come and it is similar with 3h for example we need to assign mapping `5->Z` again.

Comment: I think that the biggest issue to overcome is sequentiality. What happens if `1b` and `2c` are processed in parallel?

Comment: @maasg Thanks for comment!! I forgot to mention that we are doing  aggregation with `groupBy`. `1b` and `2c` are grouped and we know that `1b` and `2c` are connected and they are similar. so we can update `1b` with this information (same for `2c` where we know `2c` is similar with `1b`). But problem is with `2d` because we know `2` has parent `1` (for the previous event this we store in `state`) but we have to know that `1` has parent `Z` (and `Z` is also "parent"  for `2`) which is "root".

Comment: How important is the pair similarity to find the sequence `Z <-1 <-2 <-3` ?  What happens if -for example- we process `1a, 3f, 2c` ? Will we have `Z <- 1 <- 2` and `X <- 3` b/c we didn't have the `2->3` relation at the time 3 arrives?

Comment: similarity is really important. events have timestamp so as first step we transform dstream to have ordered list of events. So I assume we have `1a`, `2c`, `3f` for processing and we should have sequentially `1-2` and `2-3` pairs. Example in the question assumes `2e and 3f` are similar. But if we have similarity for `2e-3g` pair and `3f` (with earlier timestamp) has been already processed we can assume `X <- 3f` as our path. but `3g, 3h, 3i etc` should have `3->Z`. But this is edge case I would say.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the assumption is that our system is in a given state when new events arrive. To process events of type 3, our system needs to be in state `2`, right?

Comment: yes exactly. state with `2X` events should be always before state when events `3X` arrive. and `1X` is before `2X`.

Comment: I've another question: How do you obtain the next global identifier? How do I know that follows after `Z` ?

Comment: For global identifier there is no specific logic ... It could be `UUID` or counter 
 ... but something unique... just to know the "starting point" which should be unique for every "path".

Comment: I finally found some time to give it a try. It was trickier than expected but here you have a potential technique to solve this problem.

Comment: ps: Interesting question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What follows is a solution for the given problem, using a mutable reference to a 'state' RDD that we update with new results each time.

We use `transform` to tag the incoming event stream with the unique global id by doing a similarity join. This is a join "by hand" where we use a product of the two datasets and compare each entry pair-wise.

Note that this is an expensive process. There are many parts that could be changed, depending on specific characteristics of the expected stream. For example, we could replace the global state RDD by a local `map` and apply `map-side` joins for a faster similarity join, but that very much depends on the expected cardinality of the set of unique ids.

This was trickier than I originally expected. Take it only as a starting point towards a more robust solution. For example, the `union` operation on the state RDD needs regular checkpointing to avoid the DAG to grow beyond control. 
(There's a lot of room for improvement - but that's beyond a reasonable effort to provide an answer.)

Here I sketch the core of the solution, for the complete test notebook see   [UniqueGlobalStateChains.snb](https://gist.github.com/maasg/9d51a2a42fc831e385cf744b84e80479)

```
// this mutable reference points to the `states` that we keep across interations    
@transient var states: RDD[(String, (Int, Long))] = sparkContext.emptyRDD

// we assume an incoming Event stream. Here we prepare it for the global id-process 
@transient val eventsById = eventStream.map(event => (event.id, event))
@transient val groupedEvents = eventsById.groupByKey()

// this is the core of the solution. 
// We transform the incoming events into tagged events. 
// As a by-product, the mutable `states` reference will get updated with the latest state mapping. 
// the "chain" of events can be reconstructed ordering the states by timestamp

@transient val taggedEvents = groupedEvents.transform{ (events, currentTime) => 
    val currentTransitions = states.reduceByKey{case (event1, event2) => Seq(event1, event2).maxBy{case (id, ts) => ts}}                        
    val currentMappings = currentTransitions.map{case (globalId, (currentId, maxTx)) => (currentId, globalId)}

    val newEventIds = events.keys // let's extract the ids of the incoming (grouped) events
    val similarityJoinMap = newEventIds.cartesian(currentMappings)
        .collect{case (eventId, (currentId, globalId)) if (isSimilar(currentId)(eventId)) => (eventId, globalId)}
        .collectAsMap
    //val similarityBC = sparkContext.broadcast(similarityJoinMap)                   
    val newGlobalKeys = newEventIds.map(id => (id, similarityJoinMap.getOrElse(id, genGlobalId())))
    newGlobalKeys.cache() //avoid lazy evaluation to generate multiple global ids

    val newTaggedEvents = events.join(newGlobalKeys).flatMap{case (eventId, (events, globalKey)) => 
                                      events.map(event => (event.id,event.payload, globalKey))
                                     }
    val newStates = newGlobalKeys.map{case (eventId, globalKey) => (globalKey, (eventId, currentTime.milliseconds))}
    currentState = newStates              
    states.unpersist(false)                              
    states = newStates.union(states)
    states.cache()                              
    newTaggedEvents
    }
```

Given this input sequence:

```
"1|a,1|b,3|c",  "2|d,2|e,2|f", "3|g,3|h,3|i,4|j", "5|k", "4|f,1|g", "6|h"
```

We get:

Tagged Events with a global id:

```
---
1|a: gen-4180,1|b: gen-4180,3|c: gen-5819
---
2|d: gen-4180,2|e: gen-4180,2|f: gen-4180
---
3|g: gen-4180,3|h: gen-4180,3|i: gen-4180,4|j: gen-5819
---
5|k: gen-5819
---
1|g: gen-2635,4|f: gen-4180
---
6|h: gen-5819
```

And we can reconstruct the chain of events that are derived from a global id:

```
gen-4180: 1<-2<-3<-4
gen-2635: 1
gen-5819: 3<-4<-5<-6
```

-o-

Comment: woow unbelievable answer. respect! It will take few hours until I understand this :). Also thanks for notebook I will definitely try it and play with that. I have two questions for now:
`1)` I would assume following result: `gen-4180: 1<-2<-3<-4, gen-5819: 5<-6`. But it's probably related to your `#comment77490972_45191359`, right?  `2)`  what was the purpose for `sparkContext.broadcast(similarityJoinMap)` you commented out? Just for testing?

Comment: @VladoDemcak Q1) regarding the sequence, I added a "3c" in the first iteration to check the scenario where events arrive early. `3c` gets `3|c: gen-5819` and starts the `3-4-5` chain  (If my interpretation of the problem space is correct. pls correct me if that's wrong)
Q2) broadcast: that's to speed up the join, using a `broadcast join`. Only a perf optimization. I removed it when I was facing some weird results but those were due to the lazy evaluation generating multiple `globalId`s for the same events. See the `.catch` and the note next to it.

Comment: @VladoDemcak  in the notebook, the variable `currentState` is used for display purposes only   (get the data out of the `transform` and into the notebook widgets for visualization.

Comment: I didn't check `similarity` function but if `3-4-5` are "similar" then this is correct scenario. Anyway huge applause for the notebook I didn't know about `spark-notebook` so thumbs up for this. In our current solution we have accumulator to collect similar pairs and broadcast to create "global state". This is done on driver but will hit the wall in case with huge amount of data, since we have bottle neck on driver.